# ¿ Puede invocarse desde JS la modal de selección de certificados del navegador?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

En una aplicación construida con **VueJS 2** hay una vista con un formulario de login.

Necesito que el usuario tenga la opción de poder seleccionar un certificado previamente instalado en el almacén de certificados para poder hacer login. Los pasos serían: Invocar la modal, seleccionar un certificado y procesarlo para poder hacer x procesos posteriores; hacer login en este caso.

¿Puede invocarse desde JS la modal de selección de certificados del navegador?

He visto que algunas aplicaciones web lo hacen pero desconozco la tecnología utilizada…

¿Alguien sabe si esto es posible de manera nativa con vanilla JavaScript o con algún API nativo, librería de npm o similar?